# Mutex opened in Delphi application checked in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, c#-4.0, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm launching a Delphi app and create a mutex for it like this:

```
var
  AMutex: THandle;

function OpenMutex(const AMutexName: String): Boolean;
begin

  { Assume the Windows Mutext is already open }
  Result := False;

  { Is the Mutex already open? }
  if AMutex <> 0 then
    exit;

  { Try to create Windows Mutex }
  if CreateProgramMutex( AMutexName , AMutex) then
    Result := True
  else
    AMutex := 0;
end;

 function CreateProgramMutex( AMutexName: string; var AMutex: THandle ): boolean;
begin
    { Assume the new program mutex was created successfully. }
    Result := true;

    { Attempt to create a new mutex. }
    AMutex := CreateMutex(nil, False, PChar(AMutexName));

    { If we at least got a handle to the mutex... }
    if (AMutex <> 0) then
    begin

      if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then begin
        { Close the handle, since it already exists. }
        CloseHandle(AMutex);

        { Set the return to show that it was already running. }
        Result := false;
      end;
    end else
      Result := false;
end;
```

And I'm trying from C#(as a beginner) to find out if my application is already running in a console app:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class OneAtATimePlease
    {
        private static Mutex _mutex;

        private static bool IsSingleInstance()
        {
            _mutex = new Mutex(false, "my mutex name");

            // keep the mutex reference alive until the normal 
            //termination of the program
            GC.KeepAlive(_mutex);

            try
            {
                return _mutex.WaitOne(0, false);
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException)
            {
                // if one thread acquires a Mutex object 
                //that another thread has abandoned 
                //by exiting without releasing it

                _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                return _mutex.WaitOne(0, false);
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            if (!IsSingleInstance())
                Console.WriteLine("already running");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Even the Delphi app is running, IsSingleInstance is returning true. Checking the mutex in a Delphi console app using the same Delphi code is working. I'm sure that it's something obvious but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

PS: Everything is done under the same Windows user session

Comment: We can't see your code. Nobody but you knows what is behind `CreateProgramMutex`. Or what `AMutex` is. [mcve].

Comment: I've added missing parts of the Delphi implementation.

Comment: did you create a global mutex? Also you need to add a security descriptor so that it is accessible by the other process...

Comment: @whosrdaddy - No. All the code is in the question. I understand that, but why I'm seeing my mutex from another console Delphi app with the same code, but can't do that from a c# console app? And why it should be global, as I'm using it under the same session. Being global will be available over all sessions from a server, and I don't want that

Comment: @RBA: you did not include the mutex name, hence my question :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy - mutex name is a simple application name :) Nothing fancy, could be replaced with RBA for example

Comment: Besides, your code didn't work because you missed to own the mutex by your Delphi application (you could do that by setting the second parameter of the `CreateMutex` to True). But it's better to check if the C# application created new mutex as shown in the answer by @Ross Bush. Or to avoid possible single instance problem, do not create mutex there at all and only query for existing as shown in post of mine.

Comment: Delphi code is some old code which we can not touch...yet

Comment: No worries :) I just wanted to say that. If your Delphi application never takes ownership of the mutex, its state remains signalled (until some other thread takes its ownership, which could be bad scenario). And that's why your monitoring application received always positive result from `WaitOne` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that your aim is to check if a foreign application is running (by using a named mutex). Well, for such case you should not attempt to create a mutex object of the given name in your application but only try to open such. The reason is simple, if that foreign application uses such mutex to check if it is running by itself, you would actually *steal* this mutex for your application, and that foreign one would never start.

For your purpose use the [**TryOpenExisting**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194641(v=vs.110).aspx) class function. For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mutex mutex;

            if (Mutex.TryOpenExisting("My unique mutex name", out mutex)) {
                try {
                    // with the used TryOpenExisting overload you can work with
                    // the mutex object here; you can wait for it or release
                    Console.WriteLine("Application is running!");
                }
                finally {
                    mutex.Close();
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Application is NOT running!");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check if the mutex was exsiting or created.

```
Mutex appMutex = new Mutex(true, "MyMutex", out exclusive);
if (!exclusive)
{
  //Instance already existed
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I'm getting all the time the same result, even the application is running or not.

Comment: Are you logged in as the same user when testing this?

Comment: Yes. Is the same user session. Using the same Delphi code in another test console application is working. What I can't accomplish is to make it work from C# console app.

Comment: @RBA, this is correct answer and [this is what C# returns in this parameter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/mutex.cs,197).

Comment: @Victoria - Thanks for the reference, did you managed to make a small example work? Because I couldn't and I don't know why

Comment: @Victoria - I dont't have now a Delphi and Visual Studio at hand to test your example, but I'll do it tomorrow. I'm pretty sure that I had tested it like that and didn't worked. Thanks and I'll let you know if it's working so you can post it as answer and get it accepted.

Comment: @RBA, the answer is here. But after thinking about your aim (checking if a foreign application is running) I realized that you should probably avoid creating any such mutex by your checking application. If your Delphi application uses this for keeping at most single instance running, it will never start if you create such mutex in your C# application.